# Issue with RTMP Live Stream MetaData Injection and receive on Android Exo Player

Tags: android, live-streaming, wowza, exoplayer2.x

I am facing an issue with RTMP live stream MetaData injection and trigger it on client side. 
While using Wowza Stream Server I successfully inject metadata according to https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-inject-cue-points-or-metadata .

On client side using Exo Player for RTMP I add these listeners

```
exoPlayer.addMetadataOutput(new MetadataOutput() {
        @Override
        public void onMetadata(Metadata metadata) {
        }
    });

    exoPlayer.addTextOutput(new TextOutput() {
        @Override
        public void onCues(List<Cue> cues) {     
        }
    });
```

These trigger doesn't called.
I can explain further if this doesn't clear the picture.

Thanks 
Best Regards